# How to run a method from another class when button is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I'm creating a TicTacToe program for a Java project. I'm using swing with a 3x3 panel as the GUI and integrating buttons into each box for the user to click. The problem is, I do not know how to run the WinCondition method (meaning when a user gets 3 in a row). I am not able to call it to the actionPerformed method in the button class, and I don't know where else it would be viable to call.

I have two classes, one is a button class and another is the actual game which creates the panel for the user.

I've tried thinking about where else I could implement it, but I cannot because I do not know another way to execute code when a button is pressed other than the actionPerformed method.

```java
public class TicTacGame extends JFrame{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    XOButton[] buttons = new XOButton[9];

    public TicTacGame() {
        super("TicTacToe");
        setSize(400,400);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new XOButton();
            p.add(buttons[i]);
        }
        add(p);

        setVisible(true);

        }

    public int winCondition() {

        //I have left out the win condition method so this box doesn't get unnecessarily long
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TicTacGame ttg = new TicTacGame();

    }
}
```

```java
public class XOButton extends JButton implements ActionListener{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ImageIcon X;
    ImageIcon O;
    //0 is nothing, 1 is X, 2 is O
    int value = 0;
    public static int turn = 1;


    public XOButton() {
        X = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("X.png"));
        O = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("O.png"));
        addActionListener(this);
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(turn >= 5) {
            int win = ttg.winCondition();
        }

        if(turn % 2 == 0) {
            value += 2;
            turn++;
        }
        else {
            value++;
            turn++;
        }
        value %= 3;
        switch(value) {
            case 0:
                setIcon(null);
                break;
            case 1:
                setIcon(X);
                removeActionListener(this);
                break;
            case 2:
                setIcon(O);
                removeActionListener(this);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

What I expect is that whenever a button is clicked, the winCondition() method is executed to check if a user won or not.

Comment: I'm not sure that extending from `JButton` is a good choice. Remember, Swing use a form of MVC as apart of its design, meaning that the "state logic" is separated from the "visual" and "controlling" logic.  Instead, the button should be used to represent the current state of the "model".  This would suggest that you could use a "model" to maintain the state of the game, which is shared between the components that need it and that different parts of your game would be responsible for representing various information, such as the win/lose state

Answer (score 0):

there's a plenty ways to do that one of them

**DON'T**
create the win method static, so that you can access from any other class. for more info read comments below

1)you can pass a reference from TicTacGame class into XOButton class in the constructor.. so that you've the access to any other function in TicTacGame class

2)you can use interfaces....etc

Comment: Whether or not you've won is dependent on the current state of this particular TicTacGame, so making it static (option 1) probably wouldn't make sense. Option 2 is a good, simple way to do this though.

Comment: Even mentioning static for a method testing model state is a very bad idea/suggestion. Please correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by pass a reference. I do have the object "ttg" created in the main method, but calling ttg.winCondition() doesn't seem to work in the actionPerformed method.

Comment: @DhruvPatel do you know what he means by reference/object? You need to call the method on a valid reference to the currently displayed TicTacGame object. If you don't know what this means, then Google it and learn it well, since this is foundational knowledge that should be understood *before* trying to do GUI programming.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I understand what references and objects are. I just do not understand HOW to pass a reference from TicTacGame to XOButton. I cannot just create a new object, as that would just create a whole new board.

Comment: @DhruvPatel: Good, but he mentioned how -- through a constructor or method parameter.

Comment: @DhruvPatel: `buttons[i] = new XOButton(this);` and change the constructor of XOButtons accordingly to accept the parameter, using it to set a field. Myself, I wouldn't extend JButton, not for this type of program.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What is the disadvantage of extending JButton? Just curious why it wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: @DhruvPatel: oh come now. You've used setter methods where you've passed references via a parameter, what difference is a constructor's parameter?

Comment: @DhruvPatel: why not extend: It unnecessarily overcomplicates things, nowhere are you changing the innate behavior of JButton, so it isn't necessary, and it can lead to hard to debug errors, ones that have vexed me for hours, especially with Swing components that I gave x and y int fields as well as getters and setters (try it to see how it messes the GUI up royally).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That makes sense, but I use addActionListener and setIcon in my program which come from the JButton class. Also thanks for the help, the win condition checker seems to be working now.

Comment: @DhruvPatel: all of which can be done by using a standard JButton reference. Again, nowhere do you alter the innate behavior of JButton -- nowhere do you override one of its methods.